# awk logical conditions confusion

Tags: if-statement, awk, logical-operators, logical-and

Can someone please explain why does this work as expected:
`echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"")) { print }  else {print $0}}'`

```
two
three
```

`echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk '{if (gsub(/four/,"")) { print }  else {print $0}}'`

```
one
two
three
```

but this doesn't?
`echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"")) { print }}'`

Similarly, if trying to chain multiple substitutions, requiring all of them to return a non-zero count of replacements occurred, and only then print the altered result, otherwise print the original content:
`echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"") && gsub(/two/,"")) { print }  else {print $0}}'`

I am getting:

```
two
three
```

where I'd expect:

```
three
```

What am I missing here? Coming from any other programming language, I would expect this to "just work". Note that I observe same behavior in BSD and GNU awk.

EDIT:

I gather this has something to do with how awk processes multiline input:

```
echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,""))  print "found"; else print "not found"  }'

found
not found
not found
not found
```

Comment: What does your version of `echo` output given `echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n"`? Most will output exactly that string complete with literal ```\```s and `n`s. If you want to output newlines between each word on all systems (and so your question is clear) then use `printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"")) { print }  else {print $0}}'
```

can be reduced to:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk '{gsub(/one/,""); print}'
```

as it just removes `one`, if present, from every line and prints every line.

On the other hand your failing script:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"")) { print }}'
```

which can be reduced to:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' | awk 'gsub(/one/,"") { print }'
```

removes `one`, if present, from every line but then it only prints those lines for which `gsub()` returned a non-zero number, i.e. removed at least 1 `one`.

The other script you posted:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' |
awk '{if (gsub(/one/,"") && gsub(/two/,"")) { print }  else {print $0}}'
```

can be reduced to:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' |
awk 'gsub(/one/,""){ gsub(/two/,"") } { print }'
```

so it tries to remove `one`s and **if it succeeds then** it tries to remove `twos` (so it will never try to remove a `two` that didn't have a `one` on the same line, which you don't have any cases of in your input) and in the end it prints every line regardless of what else happened.

If you wanted to always remove both `one`s and `two`s and print every line then that'd be:

```
printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\n' |
awk '{gsub(/one/,""); gsub(/two/,""); print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so two things:

1. I need to parse the input so that awk treats it as a single record, by adding `BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS=""}`
2. I was confusing the `print` and `print $0` usage, thinking that the former stored the current value of modified input while the latter stored the original value, but they both store current value only.

So the solution to my last problem is:

```
echo "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="\n"; RS=""}{orig=$0;if (gsub(/one/,"") && gsub(/two/,"")) { print }  else {print orig}}'


three
```